# Symfony 4 - Heroku - Can't use my images (webpack-encore)

Tags: image, symfony, heroku, webpack

in my project symfony 4 I use all kinds of images.

I have static images for the decoration of the site. I put them in `assets/images`, and I generated them in the `public/build/images` with `webpack-encore`.

And these pictures, I manage their size with `LiipImagineBundle`

So I deployed my project on Heroku. It installs the **bundles**, the **node_modules**, generates the files with **webpack-encore** from the **assets**, and generates the **database**

**composer.json:**

```
"compile": [
      "php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --full-database --force --env=prod",
      "php bin/console d:m:m",
      "php bin/console d:f:l --no-interaction --env=PROD"
    ]
```

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress",
        "heroku-postbuild": "node_modules/.bin/encore production"
    },
```

However when I go on the application from Heroku, the site works but the images that must be displayed through LiipImagineBundle are not. Instead I have a 500 error telling me that resources do not exist. And actually if I go in the section "Sources", in the public / build / images, there are missing images. Yet they must be generated because in local (in dev), everything works perfectly.

All my required bundle for prod are in "**require**" and not "**require-dev**". And I haven't **devDependencies** in my **package.json**, all is in '**depedencies**'

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can used [heroku-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php)

It uses Composer for dependency management, supports PHP or HHVM (experimental) as runtimes, and offers a choice of Apache2 or Nginx web servers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Finally I found the worry. I used the "gb" driver for the "LiipImagine" bundle for my images. Except that Heroku did not have it, so I installed an addiction in my compose to get it and everything works :)